# VS Code - cannot enable or install again TypeScript and JavaScript Language Features extension

Tags: visual-studio-code

It began with "The TypeScript language service died unexpectedly 5 times" error. I thought to reinstall this extension so I uninstalled it and now I don't know how to install it again. I found that this is the built-in extension, so I tried to find it in Extensions tab but it is no longer on the list. I've found the vsix file containing this extension, I've installed it manually by "Install from VSIX..." option but it didn't work.
Reinstalling VSCode didn't work.

What else can I do with it?

Answer (score 15):

In VS Code go to extensions and type:

```
@builtin typescript
```

Then you will see the built-in extension and will be able to enable it again!

Refer to this picture below:

[image: built-in extension in VS Code]

Btw. I don't think there is any intuitive way of checking if this  package is enabled.

And, without it... you basically loose all `typescript.*` options in settings view in VS Code.

Comment: in 2023, it didn't solve the issue